# Not able to update(single or bulk) product attributes after doing a bulk import in M2.3.4

Tags: magento2, magento-community

I had uploaded some products using import option in my M2.3.4 site hosted on web-server. Now when i need to change/update some attributes - i cannot do that as i can't save my changes. I have been going through various posts but i cannot come to a solution. 
My crons are running fine. I did a ps aux |grep [c]onsumer & the results are;

```
> gadgetwi  614593  0.1  0.0 517400 94428 ?        S    13:51   0:01
> /opt/alt/php72/usr/bin/php /home/gadgetwi/public_html/bin/magento
> queue:consumers:start product_action_attribute.update --single-thread
> --max-messages=10000 gadgetwi  614596  0.1  0.0 517400 94424 ?        S    13:51   0:01 /opt/alt/php72/usr/bin/php
> /home/gadgetwi/public_html/bin/magento queue:consumers:start
> product_action_attribute.website.update --single-thread
> --max-messages=10000 gadgetwi  614598  0.1  0.0 517396 93472 ?        S    13:51   0:01 /opt/alt/php72/usr/bin/php
> /home/gadgetwi/public_html/bin/magento queue:consumers:start
> exportProcessor --single-thread --max-messages=10000 gadgetwi  614600 
> 0.1  0.0 517400 93604 ?        S    13:51   0:01 /opt/alt/php72/usr/bin/php /home/gadgetwi/public_html/bin/magento
> queue:consumers:start codegeneratorProcessor --single-thread
> --max-messages=10000 gadgetwi  655587 17.5  0.0 501876 78844 ?        R    14:07   0:00 /opt/alt/php72/usr/bin/php
> /home/gadgetwi/public_html/bin/magento cron:run --group=consumers
> --bootstrap=standaloneProcessStarted=1 [gadgetwi@webhosting2042 public_html]$ php bin/magento queue:consumers:start exportProcessor
```

One observation: when i run (php bin/magento queue:consumers:start exportProcessor) in CLI - i get no results. Basically nothing happens. 
Most of the solutions provided by people earlier revolve round cron and in my case i don't know how to fix it. The basic ones like max-message = 10000 is already in place.

Any insights into my issue would be much appreciated.

thanks
Harish
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In most cases this is related to cron or deadlock with some task.

Go to **database** and look for tables `magento_bulk` and `magento_operation`. Truncate both of them and then try to do mass update opration again.